# Kendo UI MVC bind Grid to DataSource from MultiSelect widgets

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are using Kendo UI MVC and need to filter a large number of records and display them in a read-only DataGrid. The page has MultiSelect widgets that each let the user select from a list of distinct values for a specific database column. After the user has entered his selections in the MultiSelect widgets he will click a 'refresh' button to update the grid. The Grid's DataSource.Ajax.Read method should pass the user's selections to the server and display the results in the Grid.

I know how to populate the MultiSelect widgets and how to return data from the server via Ajax but I'm unclear on how to pass the user's selections to Grid.DataSource.Read().

What is the best way for the button to pass the user's selections to the DataSource, fire the Read method, and display the results in the Grid?

EDIT: Putting the widgets inside the Grid's ToolBar will meet our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the widgets in Grid.Toolbar.Template